# Android Bitmap Manipulation

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bit-manipulation, mutable

Can you tell me what's wrong with this piece of code?

```
//bmp is a bitmap of already present image
int width=bmp.getWidth();
int height=bmp.getHeight();
int rgbval[]=new int[width*height];
bmp.getPixels(rgbval, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
rgbval=actual(rgbval);
Bitmap bmp2=bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
bmp2.setPixels(rgbval, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

`actual` is a function I have created to manipulate the rgb values of a bmp. By using debug functions of eclipse I have checked that it is working correctly , but when I try to recover rgb values of bmp2 , I don't get the manipulated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is due to some android bug. I have manipulated the pixels of the bitmap and i needed the pixel values to exactly the same , but when i used setPixels to set the complete pixels of the bitmap it did not work. I found the solution by using

```
index=0;
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
   for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
   {
    destBitmap.setPixel(i, j, pixelvalues[index]);

   }
```

So if i set the pixel one by one instead of all at a time somehow it works!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, see this answer: [Android Bitmap setPixel doens't work correctly? (set value, then read a different value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985819/android-bitmap-setpixel-doenst-work-correctly-set-value-then-read-a-differen)

So, it seems that if your original image does not have an alpha channel (i.e., hasAlpha() returns false), it will automatically convert the rgb values to a premultiplied format.
Is that what you're experiencing? Is bmp.hasAlpha() false?

I just tested your code with the default android icon as the bitmap, with which hasAlpha() returns true. The alpha channels in the input and output color arrays are identical. However, the red channels are off by one or two for 15 out of 2304 pixels. I didn't check the blue or green channels. I assume this is internal rounding error? I'm posting the rather verbose and used-only-for-testing code  I used just in case anyone has anything else to add.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

int width=bmp.getWidth();
int height=bmp.getHeight();
int rgbval[]=new int[width*height];
bmp.getPixels(rgbval, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
int rgbval2[] = actual(rgbval);

Bitmap bmp2=bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
bmp2.setPixels(rgbval2, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

int rgb2[] = new int[width*height];
bmp2.getPixels(rgb2, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

int alpha1[] = new int[width*height];
int alpha2[] = new int[width*height];
int red1[] = new int[width*height];
int red2[] = new int[width*height];

for(int i=0; i<alpha2.length; ++i) {
    alpha1[i] = Color.alpha(rgbval2[i]);
    alpha2[i] = Color.alpha(rgb2[i]);
    red1[i] = Color.red(rgbval2[i]);
    red2[i] = Color.red(rgb2[i]);

    if(red1[i]!=red2[i]) {
        int a1 = alpha1[i];
        int a2 = alpha2[i];
        int r1 = red1[i];
        int r2 = red2[i];


        Log.e("E", String.format("a1: %d, a2: %d, r1: %d, r2: %d", a1, a2, r1, r2));
    }
}


private int[] actual(int rgb[]) {
    int rgb2[] = new int[rgb.length];

    for(int i=0; i<rgb.length; ++i) {
        rgb2[i] = Color.argb(Color.alpha(rgb[i]), Color.red(rgb[i])/2,  
                      Color.green(rgb[i])/2, Color.blue(rgb[i])/2);
    }

    return rgb2;
}
```

and here is the LogCat output

```
a1: 64, a2: 64, r1: 30, r2: 32
a1: 64, a2: 64, r1: 30, r2: 32
a1: 142, a2: 142, r1: 58, r2: 57
a1: 142, a2: 142, r1: 58, r2: 57
a1: 216, a2: 216, r1: 56, r2: 55
a1: 216, a2: 216, r1: 56, r2: 55
a1: 57, a2: 57, r1: 6, r2: 4
a1: 59, a2: 59, r1: 6, r2: 4
a1: 231, a2: 231, r1: 90, r2: 91
a1: 216, a2: 216, r1: 95, r2: 94
a1: 216, a2: 216, r1: 95, r2: 94
a1: 217, a2: 217, r1: 57, r2: 58
a1: 216, a2: 216, r1: 88, r2: 89
a1: 199, a2: 199, r1: 66, r2: 67
a1: 199, a2: 199, r1: 39, r2: 38
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply,I checked my bitmap and it turns out it does have hasAlpha() as false . Can u suggest any way i can work around it , i.e for my code to work even on bitmaps which have hasAlpha() as false

Comment: The link in my post says that calling bmp.setHasAlpha(true); does the trick... however, that function is only available after API level 12. An easy alternative would be to manually set the alpha values of the pixels you read to 255 if hasAlpha() is false.

Comment: I am trying to design my project to work in API level 7 or 8 so i cannot use setHasAlpha() , Also setting the alpha value automatically to 255 does not seem to work either , do u have any other workaround for this

Comment: Actually when i made alpha 255 for all pixels , my bitmap containing pixels of red colors changed to blue and vice versa

Comment: 1) You can edit the image (in gimp or photoshop or whatever) to contain some transparencies and thus have an alpha channel. 2) if that still doesn't work, post your image and i'll try to replicate the issue.

Comment: Hey thank you for your replies,I debugged by code and now when i checked,setpixel() is actually setting the pixel values but when i try to store the bitmap back into the memory card or phone ,they are converted back to the original values , Can you tell me what may be the problem?

Comment: For example the following values are obtained in a run for an image which has no alpha (i.e. i set it to 255).For example  Red Green Blue were 45 13 0 before manipulation. They were set to Red--Green--Blue 44--9--7 in the bitmap. Then i store the bitmap using a bitmapcompress(Bitmap.Compress.PNG,100,fout). But when i use the getpixel() to get the value,i get 49-16-0. Why is this happening?